# Detecting querystring encoding in classic ASP

Tags: utf-8, asp-classic, character-encoding, query-string

I'm having an encoding problem I'm unsure of how to handle. We have a link that we give out (email and other means), that contains non-ascii characters (specifically `æ,ø,å` and some more). The problem is that depending on what browser the user opens said link in, the querystring we receive is encoded differently.

In most browsers it's encoded as UTF8 like this:
`%C3%A5` = `å`

However, in Internet Explorer it's encoded like ISO-8859-1 like this:
`%E5` = `å` (or it's just sent as `å` without querystring-encoding at all).

The problem is that if I read the querystring in chrome I get `Ã¥`, and not `å`, while in IE I do get `å`, so I need some way of either making sure the server takes into hand the encoding or that the client always sends in a specific encoding, and as said, the problem is that I don't have control over where the link is used.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is changing the character in the string/URL to an ASCII character not an option?

Comment: Are they encoded in the link in the source code? The link should be `<a href="...%C3%A5"`, not `<a href="...å">`

Comment: @DaveRook it was a last-resort option, cause the point was that we wanted to send name (which the user would recognize) instead of for instance ID (which is always just a number that the user has no relationship to). The links works fine when presented on our own page (cause there we control the charset), but not when sent over skype/email etc.It currently seems we will have to change it to ID's.

Comment: @Alxandr, did Esailija answer work for you ?

Comment: @DaveRook Well, I suggested it, but was told it's not viable. The problem is that these links contains names (like `/user.asp?user=Alxandr` for instance), and if we give out a link like that somebody is going to simply change it to theirs (instead of generating a new one) and it's going to fail (miserably). So it was decided that for now (at least) we'd have to use ID's instead of names. Though as said, it's not really a solution, cause it doesn't work like we wanted it to.

Comment: I fear the only safe way is to change it from the very root: don't give link with the raw name. Instead give some unique ID e.g. `<a href=".../user.asp?user=6931222">`.

Comment: server.urlencode the data before sending it out?

Answer (score 1):

Try to embed this in the top of your asp.

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
```

This *should* force all browsers to use utf-8

Comment: On subsequent requests, yes, but we're talking links that might be clicked in a mail or someplace else entirely (not in browser). In other words, the browser has no way of getting to those headers prior to the transfer of data.